# How can we use @service and @ repository stereotype in the same class in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, stereotype

How can we use @service and @ repository stereotype in the same class in Spring?

How can we expose the RESTFUL web service as the @Repository stereotype? One way of doing it is @Autowired, but I need a more detailed example of this.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  @Repository is for your DAO layer, @Service is for your service layer. You don't mix them.